# OneNote attempts to open on OneNote on Mac but under a different account

Tags: email, ms-office, keychain

Odd title but please bear with me on this!

I have a O365 Business account with 2 users with active Microsoft 365 Business Basic
(formerly Office 365 Business Essentials) licenses. The issue exists only on my Mac machine (10.15.5), as my Windows box (1903) is working as expected (something in the Keychain possibly)

First user, for examples sake, shall be alpha@test.com (this test domain is used for everything that I have)

Second user (different domain) beta@anothertest.com (this domain was recently added to my O365 account in the past 60 days)

Both email accounts are in Mail.

So many moons ago since, I've made several dozen OneNote files for my note taking, studying etc. In the last 60 days, I've purchased a new domain and added that and made a new user within my 365 account. I intend to use this user account purely for email.

Here's where the issue starts, when I visit portal.office.com, and open up one of my OneNote notebooks and request to open it with the full fat client (OneNote from App store) it then prompts me to login with my second user (beta@anothertest.com). At this point I can either proceed to login or change user. I do the latter, and states that I do not have access. I then retry and sign in with the (beta@anothertest.com) account and states also I do not have access.

Could something have been modified within my Keychain once I had added them into Mail?

As a test, I've created a Time Machine back and reloaded another Mac to break fix it and so far what I've done is searched for all traces of Office or beta@anothertest.com in Keychain and wiped them out, even went to /Library/Containers and wiped out any folders of OneNote, no change.

So StackExchange, where else can I look to stop this goram bug and get back to my note taking!

Comment: Keychain only *stores* passwords it doesn't handle authentication for individual apps.  So, the "no access" message would be coming from Microsoft.  You seem to have a bit of a complex setup with email/MS365 accounts and you could be signed in as one account trying to authenticate as another.  I would start with creating a new user account on your Mac and see if you can sign in under the new one.   Also, try contacting MS support as they would be able to better assist with account authentication issues.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Allan I've reach out to partner support and now in the process of moving my other user to a seperate O365 tennant!